# Setting a class and avoid turning output from a tibble to a list

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm trying to get the below function to work using s3 class. It is working when I dont add the class dimension and run each part seperately but when I add the class command it changes the output to a list as oppose to a tibble and then the rest of the command won't work. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

When I try to apply the below functions its returns:

Error in UseMethod("summarise_") : no applicable method for 'summarise_' applied to an object of class "growth_ind"

```
project <- function(countries)
{
 if(!require(dplyr)){
  install.packages("dplyr")
  library(dplyr)}
  
if(!require(ggplot2)){
  install.packages("ggplot2")
  library(ggplot2)}
  
if(!require(pwt9)){
    install.packages("pwt9")
    library(pwt9.1)}
  
  data("pwt9.1")

#first subsetting the data set to the variables required
  
data <- pwt9.1 %>%
  filter(country %in% countries) %>%
  select(year,isocode,rgdpna, rkna, emp, labsh) %>%
  filter(year >= 1954,
         year<= 2017)%>%
  na.omit()

#calculating the real output and capital per worker, taking the logs and the 
#first difference to obtain percentage changes

data <- data %>%
  mutate(y_pc = log(rgdpna / emp), #GDP per worker
         k_pc = log(rkna / emp), #Capital per worker
         a = 1-labsh) %>% #Calculate the capital share
  arrange(year) %>% #order by year
  group_by(isocode) %>% #for each country calculate the following
  mutate(g=(y_pc - lag(y_pc))*100, # calculating the growth of GDP per capita
         dk = (k_pc - lag(k_pc))*100, # calculating the growth rate of capital per capita
         dsolow = g - a*dk) %>% #the solow residual
  na.omit()


  class(data) <- "growth_ind"
  print(data)
}

print.growth_ind <- function(data)
{
  return(data)
}

summary.growth_ind <- function(data)
{
  solow <- data %>%
  summarise("Growth rate"=mean(g),
            "Solow residual" = mean(dsolow),
            "Capital deepening" = mean(a*dk),
            "TFP share" = mean(dsolow) / mean(g),
            "Capital share" = mean(a))
  
  return(solow)
}

plot.growth_ind <- function(data)
{
  ggplot(data, aes(x = year, y = g, colour = isocode)) + 
  geom_line()+
  labs(title="Growth rate comparison",
       subtitle = "Growth rate per capita for each country from 1954 to 2017",
       caption = "Data taken from Penn World Table 9.1",
       x="Year",
       y="Growth rate")
}

proj <- project(c("Ireland"))
summary(proj)
print(proj)
plot(proj)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice. My good old friend the solow growth model ... (;

Your main issue could be fixed by appending the `class`, i.e. by doing `class(data) <- append("growth_ind", class(data))`. This way it remains a tibble and works fine with all `dplyr` verbs. Additionally I ungrouped the data by adding an `ungroup` at the end of your data wrangling pipeline and in you `print` method I made use of `print.data.frame` as otherwise nothing was printed:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(pwt9)

project <- function(countries) {
  
  #first subsetting the data set to the variables required
  
  data <- pwt9.1 %>%
    filter(country %in% countries) %>%
    select(year,isocode,rgdpna, rkna, emp, labsh) %>%
    filter(year >= 1954,
           year<= 2017)%>%
    na.omit()
  
  #calculating the real output and capital per worker, taking the logs and the 
  #first difference to obtain percentage changes
  
  data <- data %>%
    mutate(y_pc = log(rgdpna / emp), #GDP per worker
           k_pc = log(rkna / emp), #Capital per worker
           a = 1-labsh) %>% #Calculate the capital share
    arrange(year) %>% #order by year
    group_by(isocode) %>% #for each country calculate the following
    mutate(g=(y_pc - lag(y_pc))*100, # calculating the growth of GDP per capita
           dk = (k_pc - lag(k_pc))*100, # calculating the growth rate of capital per capita
           dsolow = g - a*dk) %>% #the solow residual
    ungroup() %>% 
    na.omit()
  
  class(data) <- append("growth_ind", class(data))
  
  data
}

print.growth_ind <- function(data)
{
  print.data.frame(data)
}

summary.growth_ind <- function(data)
{
  solow <- data %>%
    summarise("Growth rate"=mean(g),
              "Solow residual" = mean(dsolow),
              "Capital deepening" = mean(a*dk),
              "TFP share" = mean(dsolow) / mean(g),
              "Capital share" = mean(a))
  
  return(solow)
}

plot.growth_ind <- function(data)
{
  ggplot(data, aes(x = year, y = g, colour = isocode)) + 
    geom_line()+
    labs(title="Growth rate comparison",
         subtitle = "Growth rate per capita for each country from 1954 to 2017",
         caption = "Data taken from Penn World Table 9.1",
         x="Year",
         y="Growth rate")
}

proj <- project(c("Ireland"))
summary(proj)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 5
#>   `Growth rate` `Solow residual` `Capital deepening` `TFP share` `Capital share`
#>           <dbl>            <dbl>               <dbl>       <dbl>           <dbl>
#> 1          3.54             1.71                1.83       0.483           0.476
print(head(proj))
#>   year isocode   rgdpna       rkna      emp     labsh     y_pc      k_pc
#> 1 1955     IRL 23016.36 0.07782067 1.194252 0.5573497 9.866440 -2.730868
#> 2 1956     IRL 22227.86 0.07958002 1.178225 0.5573497 9.845093 -2.695001
#> 3 1957     IRL 21593.21 0.07986675 1.135285 0.5573497 9.853251 -2.654279
#> 4 1958     IRL 21526.32 0.07999133 1.118528 0.5573497 9.865018 -2.637851
#> 5 1959     IRL 22753.12 0.08304243 1.110150 0.5573497 9.927963 -2.592898
#> 6 1960     IRL 23636.37 0.08525588 1.104913 0.5573497 9.970775 -2.561865
#>           a          g       dk     dsolow
#> 1 0.4426503  5.8672548 6.944282  2.7933665
#> 2 0.4426503 -2.1347642 3.586724 -3.7224284
#> 3 0.4426503  0.8157955 4.072170 -0.9867516
#> 4 0.4426503  1.1767534 1.642884  0.4495303
#> 5 0.4426503  6.2944526 4.495221  4.3046418
#> 6 0.4426503  4.2812699 3.103357  2.9075680
plot(proj)
```

[image]